# prevent recreating fragment while using navigation component

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, navigation

I'm using MVVM and navigation components. when I navigate from fragment A to B and then back to A my Fragment A will be reloaded which is not satisfied in my case. how can I prevent recreating fragments while using navigation component?
I know if I use fragment transition, I can hide and show fragments but what is the solution for this case?